# Slow Asp.Net MVC site after publish on host

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have publish my mvc site on a shared host, I'm using asp.net mvc 5 and asp.net identity for authentication.

Any time I run it for first time, it takes many time to load and show website, after first time it runs normally.I don't have any expensive operation on my site.

This is my web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please 
visit
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" 
type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="owin:appStartup" 
value="DailyReport.Services.AuthenticationServices.Startup.ConfigureAuth" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
</system.web>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" 
publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory 
type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, 
EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v13.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, 
EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DailyReportConnectionString" 
connectionString="server=.;database=DailyReport;User 
ID=MVC_User;Password=mvc8181891;" />

</connectionStrings>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
<remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
 </system.webServer></configuration>
```

I contact with my host but they told me every thing is ok.

**Update**:
I use identity in my application and put it on differente assembly.

I create a visual studio sample MVC project and publish it on my host and it loads normally.
Any specific settings required in Web.config or IIS?

thanks for help

Comment: It can depend on host, check your host settings. Shared host usually slow

Answer (score 1):

Usually it takes more time for anything to load for the first time, take into account that maybe some files need to be created or auto-configurated.